# Java SimpleDateFormat unparseable exception

Tags: java, simpledateformat

can someone elaborate why my following code is throwing a unparseable exception?

```
private Date convertSTRtoDATE(String str)
{
    str=str.trim();
    System.out.println(str+"\n20 juni 2013");
    try {
        Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy",new Locale("da", "DK")).parse(str);
        return date;
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    }
}
```

while if i change to

```
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy",new Locale("da", "DK")).parse("20 juni 2013");
```

it works perfectly?
in first occasion the println outputs

```
20 juni 2013
20 juni 2013
```

without any spaces..

Stacktrace:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20 juni 2013"    
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at com.panos.converter.convertSTRtoDATE(Crawler.java:226)
```

and the value of

```
str="20 juni 2013"
```

as i see from the debug and from output.

Comment: What is the value of `str` when you get the unparseable exception?

Comment: Because there's a newline in the first one?

Comment: i thought so also... but System.out.println(str+"20 juni 2013"); outputs: 20 juni 201320 juni 2013 so.. no newline

Comment: I would also say the newline character is probably the cause...

Answer (score 1):

This is working just fine for me -

```
public class Dates {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convertSTRtoDATE("20 juni 2013");
    }

    private static Date convertSTRtoDATE(String str)
    {
        str=str.trim();
        System.out.println(str);

        try {
            Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy",new Locale("da", "DK")).parse(str);
              System.out.println(date);
            return date;
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        }
    }
```

producing output,

```
20 juni 2013
 Thu Jun 20 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

Comment: I mean to say, there is no parsing exception in try block, the date is being parsed

Comment: now it works also for me without any changes. I think has to do with eclipse's auto build. Thank you guys

Comment: @BheshGurung, can I please know why I was downvoted? I tried and tested the same thing OP tried, I posted because I could get the parsing properly.

Comment: Don't worry, people sometimes downvote just for their bad mood, it seems. I just balanced your score. ;-)

Comment: OP clearly stated that `str` fails to parse but `"20 juni 2013"` parses successfully. Simply put the question is - why does `"20 juni 2013"` works, but `str` fail? And you are saying - `"20 juni 2013"` works.

Comment: @T-Bull, Thank you sir, you just did more than balancing the score. Here, we are all to learn so thought of asking what mistake did I make for the downvote.

Comment: @BheshGurung If you are watching closely, I have passed the string as argument to the method and it is being referred by `str` only that being parsed in the `try` block

Comment: @T-Bull: Did you even read the OP? Can you explain to me how we can consider this helpful in way, in regards to the info provided in the question itself?

Comment: *I have passed the string as argument ...* that doesn't change the fact that you are still parsing `"20 juni 2013"`, and your answer is saying that `"20 juni 2013"` works.

Comment: @BheshGurung , I understand that I am parsing a string only, but in that case, what could have been another case? According to you what should have been the question and the answer if this Unparsable exception arises? I am just asking out of curiosity because I always relate parsing to conversion of string into other objects.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: Right, downvotes should always be explained, so we can all improve ourselves. I would call this basic social behaviour.

Comment: @BheshGurung: Prasad helped the OP to discover the actual problem, even though the question was misleading. I can't see a reason to downvote the reply therein.